# Re-enable apt on TrueNAS Scale

Tags: apt, debian-based

TrueNAS Scale is Debian-based NAS.
However, `apt` and `dpkg` managers are disabled by default (for the security reasons).

Sometimes, advanced users needs to install additional utilities using the packet manager.

I'm wondering how to re-enable this possibility.

Comment: ``SSH into your system.``-> ``Open /etc/ssh/sshd_config.`` -> ``Change PermitRootLogin to yes.`` -> ``Save and restart SSH service.``

Comment: @codeapplied TNX. Currently I use System Console from UI, no SSH.
Will try with SSH in future.

Answer (score 0):

I found the next list of commands can re-enable `apt` on Truenas Scale 23.10.
I used it from System Console in Truenas UI (System Settings->Shell)

```
sudo chmod +x /bin/apt*
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/dpkg
sudo apt-get update
```